# How to map schema of a table has two different type of relationship with same table from ERD?

Tags: sql, database, schema, relational-database

I am going through the Entity relationship diagram. I just stuck at one point to understand that is if you look at the picture there are Employees and Equipment entities. Employees are connected with Equipment using INSPECT and USE relationship. Just wondering how to write SQL schema in this case.
Can anyone help me, please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In transforming ERD to a schema, you will split the two relations into 2 `ForignKey` columns in the `equipment` table
as ex:
`used_by` and `inspected_by` and both are `FK` represents `employee_id`

Hope this answers your question